# Loading views using Ui-Router on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I have a route config as such, where index is the main page, and inside the index there is an

`<div data-ui-view></div>`

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
'use strict';
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");


$stateProvider
    .state('/', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: "events.html"

    })
    .state('addactivities', {
        url: '/addactivities',
        templateUrl: "addactivity.html"

    })
    .state('managechat', {
        url: '/managechat',
        templateUrl: "chatmanagement.html"

    })
    .state('manageevent', {
        url: '/manageevent:id',
        templateUrl: "eventmanagement.html"

    })
    .state('manageactivity', {
        url: '/manageactivity',
        templateUrl: "activitymanagement.html"

    })
    .state('manageactivity.update', {
        url: '/update/:id',
        templateUrl: "updateactivity.html"

    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: "login.html"       
    });

});
```

Now, index loads, but the views does not load and I get errors like these 
`angular.min.js:11630 GET http://localhost:3000/events.html 404 (Not Found)`

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");

app.use("/php",express.static(__dirname + '/php'));
app.use("/css",express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use("/fonts",express.static(__dirname + '/fonts'));
app.use("/js",express.static(__dirname + '/js'));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));

});
```

What would be the correct way to load the views? As loading it such as index.html does not work

```
app.get('/login',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/login.html')); 
});
```